# SIP SUBSCRIBE receives multiple NOTIFY

Tags: sip, voip, pjsip, subscribe

I'm writing a SIP client, and I'm having some weird issues when using `SUBSCRIBE` to an existing client (different, freeware software)

I'm using my own server, but it's not the problem because if I'm doing a `SUBSCRIBE` from a different client (pjsip), it all works fine.

I'm sending out this `SUBSCRIBE` message:

```
SUBSCRIBE sip:3009@10.0.0.4 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.0.7:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj3893ccd****************
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:10.0.0.7>;tag=023a965a14a143eb8*******
To: sip:3009@10.0.0.5;tag=8cfb7*********
Contact: <sip:10.0.0.7:5060;ob>
Call-ID: bf5d48fe8ca0***************
CSeq: 14388 SUBSCRIBE
Route: <sip:10.0.0.5;lr;ftag=023a965a14a143eb8*********>
Event: presence
Expires: 600
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Accept: application/pidf+xml, application/xpidf+xml
Allow-Events: presence, message-summary, refer
Content-Length:  0
```

After that message, an `OK` is received, but then I'm receiving a `NOTIFY` message for every presence change that the other client did since HE registered to the server.

The problem doesn't happen with different clients..

If it matters, I'm developing on `Visual Studio 2008` on Windows 7 64bit

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the client is behaving properly. If you subscribe for presence notifications it means you want to be notified whenever the presence changes not just the first time.

Comment: The thing is, right after subscribing, I'm receiving all the notifications from before. when using PJsip. when subscribing, I'm only getting the latest. and it's not the client that filters it, since i'm looking thru wireshark

Comment: Do you unsubscribe from the client? If you restart your server in the middle of an active subscription the client has no way of knowing and could reasonably be expected to queue notifications until it can get them through. Try sending an in-dialogue SUBSCRIBE request with an Expires header set to 0 if you want to stop NOTIFY requests from a subscription.

Comment: Setting the Expires to 0 didn't change anything. same exact result
I also don't recall ever restarting the server..

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple active subscriptions between your server and the client? Just because you send a new SUBSCRIBE request does not cancel out the old subscription unless the new request is in-dialogue (has the same Call-ID, From and To tags) and an Expires header of zero. You can check the Call-ID header of the NOTIFY requests as a quick way to identify which subscription they belong to.

Comment: They all have the same Call-ID, From and To fields. only difference between the NOTIFY messages received are the `Via` fields

Comment: I might have missed something. I now see that the different client, upon receiving the NOTIFY, send back OK. I don't. could that be what I'm missing?

Comment: Yes. If you don't respond to the NOTIFY requests the client has no way of knowing they were received and according to the SIP transaction rules should re-transmit them up to 10 more times at increasing intervals.

Comment: That seems to be the behavior. I'll make the OK response, and report back. Thanks for your time

Comment: It still doesn't work. I now see that for every NOTIFY, an OK is sent, and also I can see the server forwarding the OK to the client that sends the notification, but still a lot of notifications arrive (The OK has the same call id as the notify

Comment: The Call-ID header isn't used for SIP transaction matching. You have to set the Via branch parameter and CSeq to the same values as the request, see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3261#section-17.1.3. Understanding SIP transactions is a crucial and core part of using SIP. The Call-ID, From and To tags relate to SIP dialogues which are different to transaction.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and work it out, If you'll add an answer, i'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments the issue seems to be that you are not sending a valid response to the client and therefore it is sending multiple retransmits of each NOTIFY request.

To generate a valid response the key aspect is that you have to set the Via branch parameter and CSeq to the same values as the request, see [RFC 3261, section 17.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-17.1.3).